# How can I use Zurb Foundation's Joyride post_ride_callback, but only when the user completes the tour?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I am using Rails, and I have Joyride set up, and the callbacks work, but I want to adjust it so that it only executes the `post_ride_callback` when the user completes the tour, not when they cancel it in the middle. According to their docs, it seems like I should be able to determine which took place:

```
post_ride_callback     : function (){},    // A method to call once the tour closes (canceled or complete)
```

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html

This is what I have (which works) as of now in `application.js`:

```
$(document)
  .foundation({joyride: { 
    pre_ride_callback: function() {
      console.log('tour started');
      send_tour_start_event_to_ga();
    },
    post_ride_callback: function() {
      console.log('tour finished');
      send_tour_complete_event_to_ga();
    }
  }}
 )
.foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

I am using this to send events to Google Analytics, and I would like to be able to track what % of users that start the tour actually finish it. Any thoughts on how I can have post_ride_callback only run when the tour has been completed? It seems like this guy may be on to something: https://github.com/zurb/joyride/pull/119

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Foundation 4.3.2 I faced the same problem. I wanted to load other web pages to show a new tour when the first tour was completed, but that would happen also when a user closes the tour.

Basically what I did was adding a new class (closeJoyride) on templeate > Link in the foundation.joyride.js file, so we have the control of that action.

```
 template : { // HTML segments for tip layout
    link    : '<a href="#close" class="closeJoyride joyride-close-tip">&times;</a>',
```

Then, you trigger a function when the user closes the tour:

```
$( ".closeJoyride" ).click(function() {
   $(document).foundation('joyride', 'stop');
});
```

Now your post_ride_callback will just work when the tour is complete. I guess this will work also for Foundation 5.

I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
abort_on_close           : false
```

By default, abort_on_close is true. That means the post-ride callback method will not be called. If you set it to true, it will be called.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.